# Running OTEL agent as windows service is not working

Tags: grafana, telemetry

Want to run Otel collecor agent as Windows services. So downloaded latest windows release package and run the following command to create service and start the service.

```
sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
"C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe
--config C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml" sc.exe start otelcol
```

but the service is not started and resulted with error on event viewer as

> The otelcol service terminated with the following error: An exception
> occurred in the service when handling the control request.

Agent version: 0.94.0
OS: Windows servers

Could any one point the right direction to deploy the Otel agent as windows service ?

**Updated command with quotes for folder paths:**

```
sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
\""C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe\"
 --config \"C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml\"" 
sc.exe description "Otelcol"
sc.exe start otelcol
```

Comment: Please note, that you are not supposed to edit answer into your question. If you have a solution to your problem, please post it as a proper answer (preferably with explanation)

Answer (score 0):

To run as a system service, a program must implement the
[ServiceMain protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lpservice_main_functiona?redirectedfrom=MSDN).
This means that a program must be programmed to be
a system service, and not just any program can be run
as a service.

There are programs that can wrap up any program and
provide the necessary protocol:

- [srvany-ng](https://github.com/birkett/srvany-ng)
- [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/)

Note that the only way to find out if a program can run in the
very strict environment in which services are run, is to try it.

Comment: Based on this discussion https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/6433, already otel have the option to run as windows service. I am not sure what am i missing inorder to run it as windows service.

Comment: Thanks Harrymc for quick answers. Able to run as windows service using the Sc.exe command. Missed the quotes between path in my case as path contains space in folder name. Updated command is sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
\""C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe\"
 --config \"C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml\""

Comment: I don't understand if the new syntax changed anything?