# How to create and run the windows service using powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, process-explorer

I'm trying to create a new service (AppOneTest) on windows 2016, which should be available in services.msc and whenever the service starts (AppOneTest) it should start the process explorer

```
$ServiceName = "ApplicationOneTest"
$ServiceDisplayName = "AppOneTest"
$ServiceDescription = "This launches process explorer"
$ExecutablePath = "C:\processexp\procexp64.exe"

$ScriptPath = "C:\Backup\LaunchScript.ps1"
$LaunchScript = @"
    # Script to launch processexp
    & '$ExecutablePath'
"@
$LaunchScript | Out-File -FilePath $ScriptPath -Encoding utf8

New-Service -Name $ServiceName -DisplayName $ServiceDisplayName -Description $ServiceDescription -BinaryPathName "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File $ScriptPath" -StartupType Automatic

sc.exe config $ServiceName obj= "domain\username" password= "******" type= interact

Start-Service -Name $ServiceName
```

This script will try to create a service and will try to start that service. However, when I try to start the service which was created, it's stuck and never starts.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: XY problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem And, in its current form, it is a bad idea. Please explain what you want to achieve and not your intended solution.

Comment: I was trying to achieve the execution of UI tests and the tests gets executed whenever the session is interactive only. To always keep the interactive session, I was trying to create a service and this service will launch the GUI application within user's session.
As per windows 2016, we have session 0 and session 1

Comment: Why not use Task Scheduler? Then you can launch something in the users' context.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run an interactive system service.
This is not recommended and there may be some complexities
to solve in addition to my answer.
Note that not every program is made to run using the system
service protocol, and I really doubt that Explorer is suitable.
You might find the utilities I list in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1830879/8672)
to be useful in creating ad-hoc services from such
unsuitable programs :
[srvany-ng](https://github.com/birkett/srvany-ng) and
[NSSM](http://nssm.cc/).

At a minimum, you need to have the service run under the same
user account as the logged-in user. In PowerShell, this means using a [PSCredential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential)
object that contains the user credentials.

Example code:

```
$username = "username"
$password = "password"
$securepassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $securepassword)

New-Service [...] -Credential $cred
```

References:

- [Add Credential support to PowerShell functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/add-credentials-to-powershell-functions?view=powershell-7.4)
- [Interactive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services)
- [SecureString Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring?view=net-8.0)

Comment: Please note, they're talking about "Process Explorer", which is a task manager alternative, not actually the Windows Explorer.exe process responsible for the taskbar, start menu and desktop.

Comment: @LPChip: Both Explorers are equally unsuitable to run as system services.

Comment: I don't know why I thought Process Explorer has a build-in function to run as a service itself, but just checked again and can't find it. Don't see a reason why it wouldn't be, but okay...

Answer (score 0):

Interactive services are mostly ineffective as of Windows Vista and should not be used.

Service programs must conform to a specific interface, they must interact with the Service Control Manager, signalling their status and whatnot. Process Explorer or any other average application would not do this.

You can use a service wrapper like [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/) to run arbitrary programs as services. This is a popular solution for Java server applications.

---

To run your UI tests, you should instead use a VM with auto-login configured and display sleep/locking disabled, and then run your tests in the regular session that’s always open.

Comment: Yes, I have a windows server 2016 VM which was configured with auto-logon. However, by default,  the VM will have always the lock screen and tried the below approaches to execute the UI tests......1. To unlock the windows lock screen and realized it is risky and not a straight forward approach. 2. Have tried to make the settings Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization and select Do not display the lock screen....but this always shows the lock screen if I lock it....please let me know if we have any alternatives

Comment: Well… you must not lock it. Simple as that.

Comment: Well...then this approach works only when user connects to VM and try to execute the UI tests. It will not work if a user disconnected from VM and try to execute the UI tests.

Comment: Yes, RDP is entirely incompatible with this approach. It must not be used.

Comment: Yes, taking RDP will not work. Is there any possible way to make this execution of UI tests ?